# Fortran OMP : how to do a parallel and a single task?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am a newbie in parallel programming. This is my serial code that I would like do parallelize

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer :: pr_number, i, pr_sum
  real :: pr_av
  
  pr_sum = 0
  do i=1,1000
! The following instruction is an example to simplify the problem.
! In the real case, it takes a long time that is more or less the same for all threads
! and it returns a large array
   pr_number = int(rand()*10) 
   pr_sum = pr_sum+pr_number
   pr_av = (1.d0*pr_sum) / i
   print *,i,pr_av ! In real case, writing a huge amount of data on one file
 enddo

 end program main
```

I woud like to parallelize `pr_number = int(rand()*10)` and to have only one `print` each num_threads.
I tried many things but it does not work. For example,

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer :: pr_number, i, pr_sum
  real :: pr_av
  
  pr_sum = 0
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(pr_number) SHARED(pr_sum,pr_av)
!$OMP DO REDUCTION(+:pr_sum)
  do i=1,1000
   pr_number = int(rand()*10)
   pr_sum = pr_sum+pr_number
!$OMP SINGLE
   pr_av = (1.d0*pr_sum) / i
   print *,i,pr_av
!$OMP END SINGLE
 enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

end program main
```

I have an error message at compilation time : *work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing, critical or explicit task region.*

How can I have an output like that (if I have 4 threads for example) ?

```
       4   3.00000000    
       8   3.12500000    
      12   4.00000000    
      16   3.81250000    
      20   3.50000000  
      ...
```

I repeat, I am a beginner on parallel programming. I read many things on stackoverflow but, I think, I have not yet the skill to understand. I work on it, but ...

## Edit 1

To explain as suggested in comments. A `do loop` performs N times a lengthy calculation (N markov chain montecarlo) and the average of all calculations is written to a file at each iteration. The previous average is deleted, only the last one is kept, so process can be followed. I would like to parallelise this calculation over 4 threads.
This is what I imagine to do but perhaps, it is not the best idea.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: "*writing a huge amount of data on one file*" Note that HDD are inherently sequential so it will be slower in parallel. It is not the case with SSD but you should not expect a significant speedup (possibly a loss due to internal lock in OS/drivers). As for `rand()`, the same thing applies. it mutate a seed which can only be done sequentially. If you want to parallelize this, then you need multiple rand functions operating on multiple different seeds. I am not sure there is a simple way to do that in FORTRAN but you can use things like https://www.pcg-random.org/ .

Comment: `rand()` is nonstandard and likely not very high quality. The standard Fortran PRNG generator is called using `random_number()`. But no promises for parallelism using threads are made in the standard. There are high quality parallel PRNG libraries available.

Comment: @JérômeRichard. Rand is only an example. This is not my subroutine. I want only to geneerate a number for this example. To give you some details, for rand, I will use trng (itna random nunber generator with leap frog, yarn2 and distribution01). Concerning the writing on HDD, I know the problem that it is why I want to write each num_threads numbers mod xxx.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава. Please, look at my comment to Jerome Richard.

Comment: Please explain *BY EDITING THE QUESTION* what you mean by "but it does not work". An example of not working output would be very good.

Comment: Please show the actual code and the actual outtput of that code.

Comment: No time to write an answer now but note you have a imposed an order on this thus limiting the parallelism - you will probably need an outer loop over the parallel "stages" which has to be in serial as you have a required ordering for that loop, and then parallelise an inner loop over the things that can be done at the same time, i.e. in parallel.

Comment: @IanBush. Thanks a lot. Vladimir had do it. It was the solution. I tried many things but it needed an outside loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the reduction variable inside the construct where the reduction happens is not really well defined. The reduction clause with a sum is typically implemented by each thread having a private copy of the reduction variable that they use for summing just the numbers for that very thread. At the and of the loop, the private copies are summed into the final sum. There is little point printing the intermediate value before the reduction is actually made.

You can do the reduction in a nested loop and print the intermediate result every n iterations

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer :: pr_number, i, j, pr_sum
  real :: pr_av
  
  pr_sum = 0
  !$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(pr_number) SHARED(pr_sum,pr_av)
  do j = 1, 10
    !$OMP DO REDUCTION(+:pr_sum)
      do i=1,100
      pr_number = int(rand()*10)
      pr_sum = pr_sum+pr_number
    enddo
    !$OMP END DO

    !$omp single
    pr_av = (1.d0*pr_sum) / 100
    print *,j*100,pr_av
    !$omp end single
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL

end program main
```

I kept the same `rand()` that may or may not work correctly in parallel depending on the compiler. Even if it gives the right results, it may actually be executed sequentially using some locks or barriers. However, the main point carries over to other libraries.

Result

```
> gfortran -fopenmp reduction-intermediate.f90 
> ./a.out 
     100   4.69000006    
     200   9.03999996    
     300   13.7600002    
     400   18.2299995    
     500   22.3199997    
     600   26.5900002    
     700   31.0599995    
     800   35.4300003    
     900   40.1599998
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried many things (barrier, single, master, schedule(dynamic), ...). But the solution was to create an outside loop as also suggested by IanBush in its comment.

Comment: For the `rand()`, I will use this library : https://www.numbercrunch.de/trng/ with lead frog method to be fair play.

Comment: If I may, your code does not give the result expect (as in the figure of the question) because when `omp master` is running the other threads continue. For example, if you change `int(rand()*10` to `1`, you will see the problem. I think, the omp directive should be single instead of master (master + nowait = single)

Comment: @Stef1611 OK, I did actually think whether the barrier is necessary  and I chose `master` intentionally. But it seems that it does indeed results in a race condition (reported by `-fsanitize=thread`) and the barrier is necessary.

Comment: I am worried some problem is still there but I cannot research it now.

Comment: It seems that there is no problem. Thanks for help and discussion.

Comment: Hopefully not. There was a private/shared problem in a more advanced version I used with a parallel library. I keep crashing the Intel Inspector but it seems to be a problem in that software.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. I solved it by removing `SHARED(...)` because the `DEFAULT` is ` SHARED`. Not sure of I am doing but it works. as I am discovering paralllel programming